# Why does putExtra take a key value pair and not just a value?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am going through some of the Android development tutorials, and I just came up with this general question:

Why is it that the `intent.putExtra` method takes a key value pair and not just a value?

If I want to pass a string to the new `Intent`, why not just pass the `String`? What benefits does the key have?

Comment: It's simple to discriminate between many value you put in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add more than one object to your `Intent` so you could do this:

```
intent.putExtra("name", "My Name");
intent.putExtra("age", 30);
```

If you want to get the some of the data back you need to specify which using the key:

```
intent.getStringExtra("name"); // returns "My Name"
intent.getIntExtra("age");     // returns 30
```

Comment: Easy enough! Thanks, I knew it was something obvious.

Comment: @tbraun89 : There isn't a method `getExtra(String name)` for `Intent`.  You must use methods directed at value types, e.g., `getStringExtra(String name)` and `getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)`

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply: keys allows you to pass more than one String (or Integer, Parcalable, etc) and keep them separate.